# How can i correlate a message to the camunda process before execution reaches to event handler

Tags: spring-boot, camunda

I have a camunda process in which we have a user task before the event handler, how can I send a message from the user task to the camunda process.

As the camunda flow is not waiting for event, when it is in user task then only I need to send a message to the event handler.

Comment: It would help if you can show the section of the process model

Answer (score 0):

You mean you need to send a message "into the future"? Why do you have to? Just set a data in the user task and react to the data value in an expression on a gateway. Depending on the use case, you may also consider event-based sub process.